# touchesmoved screen bounds, how can I restrict the movement of the rect out of the screen bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'am trying to restrict the movement of the rect by the screen bounds. The logic is simple, you tap **inside** the rect (doesn't metter where) and drag it. It follows your finger, and it has to be stoped when the border of the rect reached the bounds of the screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

}

then I try to figure out where the tap is and if its inside the rect I change the color of the rect

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
//NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
if (touch.view == rect) {
    rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    isSelectedRect = YES;

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint center = rect.center;

    delta = CGPointMake(point.x - center.x,
                        point.y - center.y);

} else {
    rect.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    isSelectedRect = NO;
}
```

}

after that I move this rect

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (isSelectedRect) {
        UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        rect.center = CGPointMake(point.x - delta.x,
                                  point.y - delta.y);
    }
}
```

Eventualy, I need to write one line of the code which will limit the movement the rect by bounds of the screeen. I and it would be perfect to make it with ternary operator. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `touchesMoved` method with the code below. Hope it can help you ;)

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  //NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  if (isSelectedRect) {
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(point.x - delta.x,
                          point.y - delta.y);
    CGFloat rectHeight =  rect.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat rectWidth =  rect.frame.size.width;

    CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;


    if (newCenter.x + rectWidth / 2 > screenWidth) {
      newCenter.x = screenWidth - rectWidth / 2;
    }

    if (newCenter.x - rectWidth / 2 < 0) {
      newCenter.x = rectWidth / 2;
    }

    if (newCenter.y + rectHeight / 2 > screenHeight) {
      newCenter.y = screenHeight - rectHeight / 2;
    }

    if (newCenter.y - rectHeight / 2 >= 0) {
      newCenter.y = rectHeight / 2;
    }

    rect.center = newCenter;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work properly. Just one question, when you drug it with high velocity the border of the rect doesn't touch the screen bounds. There is a small area between them. When you do it slowly, everything is ok, there is no space between rect and screen bounds. Why is that happen?

Comment: @PaSol I have updated my answer, it works now. You can try it again ;)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Everything is perfect.

Comment: Welcome @PaSol. Will be grateful if my answer can be marked as right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(boundsRect, point)) {
    rect.center = CGPointMake(point.x - delta.x,
                                  point.y - delta.y);
}
```

Here, boundsRect will be the Rectangle of device.

Answer (score 0):

You have to note that the point which you are moving in touchesMoved function is the center point of the view. In order to restrict them from going outside the viewBounds you must check whether the bounds of the draggable view is exceeding your translation point.

to get the actual bounds

```
CGPoint center = rect.center;
CGSize size = rect.size
CGRect originalRect = CGRectMake(center.x - size.width/2, center.y - size.height/2, size.width, size.height);
```

Now check whether the given rect is within the desired rect.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(boundsRect, originalRect)) {
    // Here change the center of the view 
}
```

I Hope this helps.